# Query OnPremise AD for Specific AD attributes to check Office 365 or not

Tags: powershell, active-directory, office365, exchange-server

I need to determine which email address recipient is currently already in Office 365 or still on-premise.

The below simple PowerShell script is only working to export the list of the users in a particular member of AD Groups:

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter {Name -like '*IT*'} | Select-Object @{ n='Group'; e={ $_.Name } }, @{ n='Members'; e={ (Get-ADGroup $_.DistinguishedName -Properties Members | Select-Object Members).Members } } |
    Get-ADGroupMember -Recursive |
        Get-ADUser -Properties Mail | Select-Object Name, sAMAccountName, Mail |
            Export-CSV -path "C:\Group_members.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

I just wanted another column which shows if the user is already in Office 365 or Still OnPremise.

There is another Expert posting:

```
Get-MsolUser -UsageLocation US -All |
    Where-Object isLicensed -eq $true |
    Select-Object -Property DisplayName, UserPrincipalName, isLicensed,
    @{label = 'MailboxLocation'; expression = {
            switch ($_.MSExchRecipientTypeDetails) {
                1 {'OnPremise'; break}
                2147483648 {'Office365'; break}
                default {'Unknown'}
            }
        }
    }
```

But I am not sure how to combine the script above?

I also have tried the below script to query OnPremise AD with the specific attributes, but still failed no result returned?

```
Get-ADUser-Filter *-Properties *|
Where-Object {($_.msExchRemoteRecipientType-eq4) -and
  ($_.msExchRecipientDisplayType -eq '-2147483642') -and
  ($_.msExchRecipientTypeDetails -eq '2147483648') -and
  ($_.proxyAddresses -contains "*.onmicrosoft.com*")
}
```

Comment: is this a hybrid exchange environment or are users strictly office 365 or OnPremise? The reason I ask is because hybrid users will still have the onmicrosoft.com as a proxy address in on-premise AD.

Comment: Also, are you syncing users with Azure AD connect? If so, then we should expect the same userprincipalname values in office 365 and local AD, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no property on the user via Get-ADUser called targetAddress

Though if you put it in your select, it will show up in the results as empty because you are allowed to add any property name you want in a select, whether it exists or not.

And this also is a syntax error

```
$_.msExchRecipientDisplayType = '-2147483642')
```

You are also not using comparison operations correctly, but you are using assignment operators. Meaning the -eq vs '='.

```
$_.msExchRecipientDisplayType -eq ...


# Find all cmdlets / functions with a target parameter
Get-Command -CommandType Function | 
Where-Object { $_.parameters.keys -match 'targetAddress'} | 
Format-Table -Autosize


# No results

Get-Command -CommandType Cmdlet | 
Where-Object { $_.parameters.keys -match 'targetAddress'} | 
Format-Table -Autosize


# No results



Get-Command -CommandType Function | 
Where-Object { $_.parameters.keys -match 'Address'} | 
Format-Table -Autosize


# No results

Get-Command -CommandType Cmdlet | 
Where-Object { $_.parameters.keys -match 'Address'} | 
Format-Table -Autosize

< #
CommandType     Name                        ModuleName
-----------     ---- ----------
Cmdlet          New-ADDCCloneConfigFile     ActiveDirectory
Cmdlet          New-ADOrganizationalUnit    ActiveDirectory
Cmdlet          New-ADUser                  ActiveDirectory
Cmdlet          Set-ADOrganizationalUnit    ActiveDirectory
Cmdlet          Set-ADUser                  ActiveDirectory
#>


Get-Command -CommandType Function | 
Where-Object { $_.parameters.keys -match 'EmailAddress|proxyAddress'} | 
Format-Table -Autosize


# No results

Get-Command -CommandType Cmdlet | 
Where-Object { $_.parameters.keys -match 'EmailAddress|proxyAddress'} | 
Format-Table -Autosize
< #
CommandType Name       ModuleName     
----------- ----       ----------     
Cmdlet      New-ADUser ActiveDirectory
Cmdlet      Set-ADUser ActiveDirectory
#>


Clear-Host
(Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties *)[0] | 
Get-Member -Force | 
Select Name, MemberType | 
Format-Table -AutoSize


Name                                            MemberType
----                                            ----------
...
EmailAddress                                      Property
...
mail                                              Property
mailNickname                                      Property
...
msExchArchiveQuota                                Property
msExchArchiveWarnQuota                            Property
msExchCalendarLoggingQuota                        Property
msExchCoManagedObjectsBL                          Property
msExchDumpsterQuota                               Property
msExchDumpsterWarningQuota                        Property
msExchELCMailboxFlags                             Property
msExchHomeServerName                              Property
msExchMailboxGuid                                 Property
msExchMailboxSecurityDescriptor                   Property
msExchPoliciesIncluded                            Property
msExchRBACPolicyLink                              Property
msExchRecipientDisplayType                        Property
msExchRecipientTypeDetails                        Property
msExchTextMessagingState                          Property
msExchUMDtmfMap                                   Property
msExchUserAccountControl                          Property
msExchUserCulture                                 Property
msExchVersion                                     Property
msExchWhenMailboxCreated                          Property
...
proxyAddresses                                    Property
...
#>
```

As noted from the other site, this also this...

```
($_.proxyAddresses -contains "*.onmicrosoft.com*")
```

... really should be this...

```
($_.proxyAddresses -match "onmicrosoft.com")
```

... or this...

```
($_.proxyAddresses -like "*.onmicrosoft.com*")
```

***Update for the OP***

```
After getting back to my test environment, the below works for the use case.

Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties msExchRemoteRecipientType,proxyAddresses,msExchRecipientDisplayType,msExchRecipientTypeDetails | 
Where-Object {($_.msExchRemoteRecipientType -eq 4) -and
  ($_.proxyAddresses -match "onmicrosoft.com") -and
  ($_.msExchRecipientDisplayType -eq '-2147483642') -and
  ($_.msExchRecipientTypeDetails -eq '2147483648')
}
```

Also, correction, not that you need it for what you are after, since the proxyAddresses return the same thing, when you hit that remote O365 mailbox, you do get a targetAddress property, it's just not on the on-prem mailboxes, hence the reason, the proxyAddresses may be more prudent for you to use for consistency.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties msExchRemoteRecipientType,proxyAddresses,targetAddress,msExchRecipientDisplayType,msExchRecipientTypeDetails | 
Where-Object {($_.msExchRemoteRecipientType -eq 4) -and
  ($_.proxyAddresses -match "onmicrosoft.com") -and
  ($_.targetAddress -match 'onmicrosoft.com') -and 
  ($_.msExchRecipientDisplayType -eq '-2147483642') -and
  ($_.msExchRecipientTypeDetails -eq '2147483648')
}
```

Comment: No worries...glad it was helpful